# Is there easy way to get to the Worldbuilding election site?

Tags: discussion, support

Being active user on this site, I am constantly curious who is running up for the moderators of this site. However, I did not find any easy way how to get to the election site than just remembering the [link to worldbuilding election site](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/election).

Is there some mouse-only option I could access the election site?

P.S.: Good luck to all running for the Moderators. Just Primary itself will be really hard to decide, because there are already at least 6 people I would like to see as moderators

Comment: For me its always on the right hand side under "upcoming events". Is that no option for you?

Comment: What about bookmarks?

Comment: In the primary you can vote up or down on each candidate.  It's only in the final stage of the election that you have to narrow it down to three votes (which is going to be really, really hard).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a direct link in the sidebar, under the *UPCOMING EVENTS* section:

[image]

This link is also availiable on meta:

[image]

These will take you directly to the site you requested and stay there until the election is over.

Comment: Blind, blind, blind. What else can I say? :)

Comment: @PavelJanicek I know [that feel](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3010/for-how-long-are-moderators-elected), bro... ;)